# Open GL version 2.1 instead of 3.2 on OS X 10.8

Tags: opengl, osx-mountain-lion

I have a late 2009 Macbook http://support.apple.com/kb/SP579
I upgraded the operating system everytime a new one came out, so I'm using 10.8 Mountain Lion now. I was trying to get a program to work when the developer suggested I check my Open GL version with glxinfo.

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M OpenGL Engine
OpenGL version string: 2.1 NVIDIA-8.12.47 310.40.00.05f01
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
```

According to this https://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/
I should have Open GL version 3.2, but I don't. I've also looked for newer Nvidia drivers, but the nvidia drivers download website doesn't show any for OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), GeForce 9400M. The Open GL website says that unlike other operating systems, Open GL is updated along with the other OS X updates.

What do? How do I get OpenGL to 3.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I check my Open GL version with *glxinfo*

glxinfo goes through the X11 server. The OpenGL support of the X11 server which is shipping with OS X is rather limited. You must check with a tool that queries the native OpenGL API of OS X, not the GLX emulation layer.

Comment: Assuming said program actually implemented windowing using the native OGL API of OS X, and not just X11.